# Magento 2 : Call custom file in virtual product view page

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, product-view, phtml

I want to call my custom phtml file in virtual product's view page. That file will call within form of that page so my data are post on add to cart.

I already develop a code for this purpose and working fine on add to cart page.But when I am on update cart page of this product that time file is not calling.

Please have a look :

namespace/mymodule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
           <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Product\View\Type\Virtual" template="Namespace_Modulename::product/view/type/virtual.phtml"/>
      </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Have you same file call in cart page ?

Comment: you can check using adding after or before in block tag.

Comment: @SHPatel Yes I am calling same file.

Comment: @Rakesh can you please give me an example

Comment: Do you want your custom template instead of `product/view/type/default.phtml` ?

Comment: @PrashantValanda no I only want  custom block

Answer (score 0):

you can try using,
you can set blockname as your position name like ,`product.info.price`

```
<block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Product\View\Type\Virtual" template="Namespace_Modulename::product/view/type/virtual.phtml" after="{blockname}" />
```

Or

```
<block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Product\View\Type\Virtual" template="Namespace_Modulename::product/view/type/virtual.phtml" before="{blockname}" />
```

Comment: Do you know which block name I have to used here ? Because I tried many blocks by their reference name but can not get success.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your theme defaul.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Product\View\Type\Virtual" template="Namespace_Modulename::product/view/type/virtual.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Is it not possible to put in catalog_product_view_type_virtual instead of default.xml ? why ?

Comment: Because of catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml can not call on update cart item.

Comment: I tried this and my file is called in both case.But as I said it is calling out of Form passed to cart.So my data will not pass. :(

Comment: Hi @SureshChikani my custom phtml file is not calling in all product view pages

Comment: Please refer the below link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267766/magento-2-custom-phtml-file-not-calling-to-all-products-view-pages

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in file **Namespace/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
         <referenceContainer name="product.info.type">
                <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Product\View\Type\Virtual" after="product.info.virtual" template="Namespace_Modulename::product/view/type/virtual.phtml"/>             
         </referenceContainer>      
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This will add out of form of product view page.So my data will not post on add to cart.