# Magento 2 custom phtml file not calling to all products view pages

Tags: magento2, product, view

I have created custom phtml file, but that file is calling to all the products magento2

Please find the below code:

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content" >
            <block
                    class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\RewardMesg"
                    name="reward_frontend_msg"
                    template="Vendor_Module::product/view/rewardMesg.phtml" before="product.info.addtocart"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

My block code is:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class RewardMesg extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * ProductView constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        Registry $registry
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if (is_null($this->product)) {
            $this->product = $this->registry->registry('product');
        }

        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

Help me appriciate.

Thanks

Comment: You want call your phtml in all the product pages ??

Comment: Yes @Prathap Can you please send the exact code

Comment: @shivashankarm check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create below file and add below code after check it

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\RewardMesg" name="reward_frontend_msg" after="product.info.price" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/rewardMesg.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Please don't forget to clear cache after change in  xml files**

Comment: Hi @Rakesh it is working fine but i would like add it before qty section

Comment: i have updated my answer please check it

Comment: Hi @Rakesh the above code is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Add the catalog_product_view.xml in the below path in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

then add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\RewardMesg"  name="reward_frontend_msg" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/rewardMesg.phtml" before="product.info.addtocart" after="page.main.title">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

and place your phtml in the respective path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product/view/rewardMesg.phtml

Your phtml will load in after product title and before add to cart button.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

1. > app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Blockname" name="reward_frontend_msg" template="Vendor_Module::product/view/rewardMesg.phtml"/>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
2. > app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/product/view/rewardMesg.phtml

   ```
   //Diplsay the bellow code where you want to block on product page

   <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('reward_frontend_msg'); ?>
   ```